# Replace a line line libc.so

Tags: linux, sed

I am a newbie to SED ; tried the options given previously but receiving errors. Command tried is :

```
sed 's/GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.0 /usr/lib/uclibc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED ( /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 ) )/GROUP ( ../../lib/libc.so.0 ../usr/lib/uclibc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED ( ../../lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 ) )' < libc.so
```

Error received is :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'
```

Need to change libc.so file using SED:

```
GROUP (/lib/libc.so.0 /usr/lib/uclibc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED (/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 ) )
```

to relative path meaning something like below :

```
GROUP ( ../../lib/libc.so.0 ../usr/lib/uclibc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED (../../lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 ) )
```

Let me know whether there are any better way to do the same. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to edit the actual binary file, per the end of your command `... < libc.so` OR are you modifying a path in a config file? Best to give a little more context on your question. Also ... New seds may be much more powerful, but I don't see any sed dealing well with NULLs etc that are embedded in a binary file. Also, it looks like you'd be changing the size of the file which would mess up location of all the functions that are stored in there. Better to post a new question about how to build lib.so with alternate names with tags of linux/unix/make/c. Good luck.

Comment: libc.so is not a binary file ; this is a linker script generated by GCC during build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/GROUP\ (\/lib\/libc.so.0\ \/usr\/lib\/uclibc_nonshared.a\ AS_NEEDED\ (\/lib\/ld-uClibc.so.0\ )/GROUP\ (\ ..\/..\/lib\/libc.so.0\ ..\/usr\/lib\/uclibc_nonshared.a\ AS_NEEDED\ (..\/..\/lib\/ld-uClibc.so.0\ )\ )/g' libc.so
```

Comment: The SED version used is 4.1.5 in my machine ; the SED command above is not changing libc.so file. It is observed that time stamp of libc.so changes after running the above command but the data aka. line remains unchanged ;

Comment: if i can get access to terminal, we can share that terminal session and i will guide you that how to debug this sed script step by step. as it is very hard to be successful in one go.

Comment: Thanks Frank. will not be able share a terminal ; let me put in sme learning time and start debugging ; maybe a good start to kickoff SED learning

Comment: No problem. just one tip for you to do it yourself. do not try to apply sed command to whole string. apply it in steps. and one more thing that you should learn about ESCAPE characters in bash. read about them and how to use them in sed. it will be very helpful for you.